# Error while connecting remotely

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

i m using sql server 2005 with service pack-2. 
When I connect sql server with by registering the remote server with IP, username and password. I have done all the neccessary setting for connecting remotely "SQL Server 2005 Surface Area Configuration".
  i got following error while connection:

This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers. (ConnectionDlg)

Can you please provide me possible reasons for the above mentioned error.

Thanks,
Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

I would also add that this can also happen if you are trying to connect to a lower version too!

I would also suggest checking which version of SQL 2005 you are attempting to connect to and make sure it is a RTM or higher, and not an older CTP release.

The other possibility is that there is another SQL Server instance (not 2000, or 2005) running on the IP that you are connecting to. Try connecting via server or instance name if possible.

Kev

Answer (score 0):

Only reason for this can be if you are trying to connect to higher version of SQL Server. Please check again if it is SQL Server 2005 or 2008 you are trying to connect.

Here is similar problem and solution for it at [sql-server-performance](http://sql-server-performance.com/Community/forums/p/24970/138904.aspx) site

edit:- also if you have installed some version of SQL Server 2008 it may also break Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Right - to get to the bottom of this I would check the version from the command prompt, from the machine experiencing the problem:

```
sqlcmd -Q "SELECT @@VERSION" -S myserver\myInstance -U myUserName -P myPassword
```

This will give you the version of SQL Server you are connecting to. 'sqlcmd' will run against old and new versions of SQL Server.

You can use the same technique, with different SQL to identify which server you are really connecting to, etc.